# How to append command to docker-compose.yml without override existing?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker-compose.yml I have a service

```yml
app:
    image: yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.1-apache
    volumes:
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      - ./:/app:delegated
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

So I want to execute command `yii migrate --interactive=0` when container is started. But if I just add string

```
command: "yii migrate --interactive=0"
```

It override command that already specified in `yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.1-apache` dockerfile. How can I append command, not replace? Is it possible?

I already googled for this problem, but most popular solution is "create your own dockerfile". Can I solve this without create/modify dockerfile or shell script, only with docker-compose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you would have to define your own `ENTRYPOINT` [in your `docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint). Besides building your own Dockerfile, there is no way around this.

As much as I am searching, I cannot find a `CMD` instruction in this image's Dockerfile, though. So [this](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/8203d502a18ecfe79ac011f85843754fb524b899/7.3/stretch/cli/Dockerfile#L224) is probably what's being used.

I'm not familiar with PHP, so I cannot estimate what you would have to change to run a container with your specific needs, but these are the points that you should have a look at.

Answer (score 3):

You can include the pre-existing command in your new command.  Now understand that everything in those commands can be called from sh or bash.  So look up the existing command by doing an:

```
docker image inspect yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.1-apache
```

Then check the command in Config { Command }.  (Not ContainerConfig.)  So if the existing command had been:

```
"start-daemon -z foo-bar"
```

then your new command would be:

```
sh -c "start-daemon -z foo-bar; yii migrate --interactive=0"
```

Now you'll have the existing command plus your new command and the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Worked for me in principle, with some changes:

1. `docker image inspect [image] | grep -i cmd -A4` to see what the current command is, which for me was `apache2-foreground`
2. Put the existing command __AFTER__ my new command: `command: sh -c "/myscript.sh; apache2-foreground"`